# SQL command to convert all tags in lowercase?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a SQL query command to convert every single tag in every post ever used to be converted into lowercase.

Comment: Yes, because for one small task one should go and study an entire programming language. Gimme a break, will ya?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this SQL query:

```
UPDATE wp_terms SET name=LOWER(name);
```

Comment: Much obliged!..

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad that i was able to help.